# Pushing array of objects data via service for multiple controllers angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

new to AngularJS and trying to figure out how to pushing an array of objects data (not input strings) between controllers. Currently, my code pushes data into one controller('ChooseTabCtrl') but I want to push to another controller ('ListTabCtrl') so that the list displays on another page. I'm confused b/c most examples show only when a user enters a string of text. My project adds a fave by clicking a button. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There are several approaches, but i guess in your case the best approach would be to define a service where you persist your favourites. So you can use them from both controllers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a service for this. Like:

```js
.service('FavoritesService', function(){
    var favorites = [];

    this.getFavorites = function(){
        return favorites;
    };

    this.setFavorite = function(favorite){
        favorites.push(favorite);
    };
});
```

Set your favorites:

```js
...
if (!$scope.myFaveItems.some(isAlreadyPresent)) {
    $scope.myFaveItems.unshift(item);
    FavoritesService.setFavorite(item);
}
...
```

Use it in your ListCtrl:

```js
.controller('ListTabCtrl', function($scope, FavoritesService) {
    $scope.myFaveItems = FavoritesService.getFavorites();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply this is perfect!!